# Uncaught ReferenceError: CRM is not defined whilst open the "directories" page on the admin page

Tags: joomla, migration

I moved my civicrm installation from Drupal to Joomla (well testing the migration). So far all seems to be ok.. However when I open the "directories" page via the admin page I get a unstyled page that is throwing the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: CRM is not defined

Remove already the cache and cleaned some known directories but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Resource URLs and directories need to be updated.

Since you're having trouble opening the directory page, try [using an override](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/) in `civicrm.settings.php`.

Comment: Did that, and it wasn't working. Just did a clean joomla and civicrm installation and I'm running into the same issue with that installation.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate :(  Could you check the Developer Console (F12 in your browser) and check the Network tab to see if you've got 404 errors on JS files?  That might shed some light.

Comment: Just checked it, only 200 results.